# How to make a space in the filename the condition in a bash while loop?

Tags: bash, loops, scripting, filenames

This works:

```
while [ -f *" " ]
```

But this doesn't:

```
while [ -f *" "* ] # edited per OPs comment
```

I'm sorry if I'm asking something silly.
I've used the search function, but all I could find was questions about how to deal with spaces in filenames, not how to make that the condition to target a file.

Comment: Why did you escape the globs in the second test? That being said this isn't going to work for you the way you want. If you want to test whether any files with a space in the name exist then you need to expand that second glob (without the escaping slashes) into an array (or similar) and check for length/etc. This test will fail on multiple files.

Comment: Oh! When I was writing the question, the draft didn't show the globs without escaping them. I'm not including the slashes in my command, sorry about that.

Comment: Ah, ok. The rest of my comment still applies though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either `while [ -f *" " ]` or `while [ -f *" "* ]` won't work if the globbing matches multiple files. For multiple files, the test condition becomes like:

```
[ -f file1 file2 ... ]
```

which is invalid.

For Example, In Bash:

2 matches will throw *binary operator expected* error message

more than 2 matches will throw *too many arguments* error message

---

You probably want this:

```
for file in ./*" "*;
do
  echo "$file"
done
```

Or if you want a loop if a filename contains space in it, then:

```
while [[ "$filename" == *" "* ]];do
   echo filename conatins space
done
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to keep executing a command only if there's a space in a filename? (using any space on any filename as the trigger for a general command). Thank you for fixing the question also!

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to *test* whether a filename is matching a glob pattern is to use `case`:

```
for f in *; fo
    case "$f" in
        *' '*)
            printf 'file "%s" is spacing out\n' "$f"
            ;;
    esac
done
```